How to get new access token from refresh token in salesforce?
everyone.
Nice to meet you here.
I got some problems in salesforce integration with web oauth flow and hope someone to help me.
I want to get new access token from refresh token.
So, I upload detail code and screenshots.
code
Result:
result
Connected App Configuration:
conf1
conf2
conf3
Please help me.

please do not ppst pictures of text
... post the text instead ...  https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/420624/how-to-fix-invalid-client-id-error-in-authentication-to-get-new-access-token-in

You have to use scope with api, id, refresh_token.
Please use the following url for oauth-login:
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={SALES_KEY}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&scope=api%20id%20refresh_token
Ref:
https://medium.com/@bpmmendis94/obtain-access-refresh-tokens-from-salesforce-rest-api-a324fe4ccd9b
Get refresh_token for Connected App in SalesForce
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=5
https://www.useparagon.com/integration-error-solutions/salesforce-invalid-grant-expired-access-refresh-token

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
